# looping throught each row till the end of a 2d array of integer in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

so basically I got a 2d array in a table.
table SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table_name
(
"Person_Id" numeric(24,0) NOT NULL,
"Items" integer[],
);
```

so if I do this

```
select "Items"[:][:] 
from public.table_name;
```

I would get all the elements that I added manually

[image]

I put those values manually, and I tried this

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..500 LOOP
    update public.table_name
    if("Items"[i][1] == null)
        then exit;
    end if;
    set "Items"[i][1] = 41
    where "Items"[i][1] = 6;
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

I don't want it like this but what I want is the loop to stop when my Items are done at the end. for the person_id 1, I need to do run the loop 3 times to get all elements and I know that but for each person, it's not always 3, it can vary, so how can I limit the loop so that it doesn't run more than what's needed. please help me
FYI, the above code with the if clause gives me an error.

Comment: it doesn't matter which version, I just wanted the loop to stop at the end of the array, nothing more

Comment: Instead of items in an array, make a join table. Then there's no need for a loop.

Comment: i need array because if i use join table, then it means that the table would be having 320 columns and i think its highly unoptimised, so yes i have to use array

Answer (score 0):

If you have to loop in SQL, there's probably a better way.

Instead of an array, this is much easier and faster as a join table. They also enforce [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), meaning you can't refer to an item which does not exist. Join tables are how lists are traditionally stored in SQL.

Assuming `{{1,4},{2,4},{3,4}}` means they have 4 of item 1, 4 of item 2, and 4 of item 3...

```
create table people (
  id bigserial primary key
);

create table items (
  id bigserial primary key
);

-- The join table for the items each person has.
create table peoples_items (
  item_id bigint not null references items(id),
  person_id bigint not null references people(id),
  quantity int not null,

  -- A person can only one record per item.
  unique(item_id, person_id)
);
```

If I'm understanding your update, you want to change any instance of item 41 to item 6. You can do that in a single update.

```
update peoples_items
set item_id = 41
where item_id = 6;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=10abf5f122e114b19f41f948574bec51).

Other notes:

- Don't quote column names if you don't have to, it forces you to use the exact case.
- Use a simple `bigserial` for primary keys. If there's some sort of business specific key make that a separate column.

Comment: The reason why I used an array is that a person can have more than 1 type of item and more than 1 item of the same type. How can your model satisfy my requirement?

Comment: @Roshanaby Both work fine. If you're having a problem making it work, please provide more detail; you can supply a dbfiddle link.

Comment: @Roshanaby This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How about instead of trying to replicate the 2D array, tell me what information are you actually storing.

Comment: as i said before, a person can have more than one item and each item can be more than 1. in the array the first column would be item id whereas the second column would be item number. now how would the model you should me be capable of storing this kind of data for each person without using array?

Comment: @Roshanaby By "Item number" you mean the quantity? So `{{1,4},{2,4},{3,4}}` means they have 4 of item 1, 4 of item 2, and 4 of item 3? Add a quantity column to the join table. Probably also get rid of the x and y. Join tables are how you stores lists in SQL.

Comment: @Roshanaby I've updated the answer and demo to match your description. If you're just learning SQL, avoid arrays and look more into "join tables".

Comment: I see what you did there, i like what you did but dont you think that will increase the number of rows a lot when i have like 100k customers and each having approx 40 items with them, i mean number of rows would be like 40 x 100k = 4 million rows. would it affect the performance?

Comment: @Roshanaby This is what SQL databases have spent the last 50+ years optimizing. This will be wicked fast because item_id and person_id are [indexed](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) (keys are automatically indexed, other columns you need to make indexes). Instead of having to search the whole table, `where item_id = 6` uses the index to get exactly the rows which contain item 6. In contrast, you'd try to update all 100k customers 500 times: 50 million.

Comment: yes you were right, i was actually new to databases, now i got a lot more knowledge on it, i totally understand what you mean.

Comment: @infernus Huzzah!